# Best way to display list of object in angular dart

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have the following data structures:

```
Map<String, MyClass> items;
```

A map of all my items I have loaded from the database.

```
List<String> selectedItems;
```

The currently selected items to display in a list.

I now want to display the list in a ngFor loop in a html page. How would I write the access function to the items? It should of course also detect updates in the objects.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of selectedItems">
  {{ items[item].name }}
</div>
```

The items themselves are from a redux store. So whenever something in the item changes also the object is recreated as a copy. But the list is only recreated if the selection changes.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You write "The currently selected items to display in a list." but in `*ngFor` you iterate `items`. What is `selectedItems`?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant selectedItems. I now updated my question and I didn't think about being able to access with the key the values from the map! Will try that now.

Comment: Wohoo it works, so the answer is `let key of selectedItems` with `{{ items[key].name`. So it would b great if you add this fourth option to your answer and I happily accept it!

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to access the values you can use

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items.values">
  {{ item.name }}
</div>
```

if you want to use keys and values you can do

```
<div *ngFor="let key of items.keys">
  {{ key }} - {{ items[key].name }}
</div>
```

if you want to use `selectedItems` use

```
<div *ngFor="let item of selectedItems">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

if the selectedItems contains the keys, you can use

```
<div *ngFor="let item of selectedItems">
  {{ items[item].name }}
</div>
```